# Returning generic object from method instead of Object

Tags: java, object, generics, types, gson

```
static class Person {
    String name;
    ArrayList<Person> friends;

    public Person(String name, ArrayList<Person> friends) {
        this.name = name;
        this.friends = friends;
    }
}

static class Converter {

    String raw;
    Gson gson;

    public Converter() {
        this.gson = new Gson();
    }

    public <T> T get( Class<T> cls ) {
        return gson.fromJson( raw, cls );
    }

    public void set( String json ) {
        this.raw = json;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    ArrayList<Person> friends = new ArrayList<>();
    friends.add(new Person( "craig", new ArrayList<Person>() ));
    friends.add(new Person( "andrew", new ArrayList<Person>() ));
    Person alex = new Person(
            "alex",
            friends
    );

    String rawJson = gson.toJson( alex );

    Converter c = new Converter();
    c.set( rawJson );
    Person p = c.get( Person.class ); //This gives an incompatible type error
}
```

I have a class Converter that I'm trying to return any object from. The idea is you give it raw json, and when you get( Person.class ) from it, you'll get a Person object.

This is a basic example of the problem, but why will the get() method only return an Object, and not a Person object?

Comment: I tried the code it worked for me

Comment: @KevinWallis yes I just have as well. Seems to be working now. Not sure why

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need an `instanceof` check.

I'm not using GSON but org.jsons get Method always returns an Object.

There are other Methods like `getBoolean()` , `getInteger()` etc.

So you have to use this Methods to get an explicit Datatype or you check it with `instanceof`and cast it.

Comment: gson.fromJson( raw, cls ); will return an object of type cls. There is no need to cast. Weirdly, this issue seems to have resolved itself and my method now returns correctly. I will update this if I find out why

Comment: Then it's just java.

Comment: Sometimes it does what it wants